# Is public manifest.mpd a issue?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4

I have a public manifest.mpd file. Is it considered a security issue? It has something called cenc:pssh value so i am bit scared if its okay to be public or not?

Answer (score 1):

pssh does not contain any private or secure content. In fact is specifically designed to be attributable.

Comment: And what about the playready header? I have my play ready header also public which contains KID value? Is that a bad idea?

Comment: Nope. KID is required to be public, otherwise the player could not request the decryption key, and the media could never be played by anyone. The KID is also duplicated in the mp4 files (as is the pssh)